# Use UIDocument or KVS when saving to iCloud?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, icloud

I am working on an iOS app that I want to use `iCloud` for storing documents/presets. 
As you can see in the screenshots its quite a simple solution I have now. I Simply archive a list of presets (title, description, expression, and source). What would be the best solution for storing those presets/documents in iCloud so you can continue your work on iPhone/iPad/ (Maybe even OS X)?

Inherit from `UIDocument`, or use KVS with `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore`?

[image: iPad image of application]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest **NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore** since you are not storing an actual document and more configuration setting, plus **NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore** has the auto synchronize with your app and iCloud that you don't have to worry about. Also this is basically free memory in iCloud that doesn't count against the users memory allocation on iCloud.

If you are storing things like images, Documents would be a better fit.

Good example here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/StoringPreferenceDatainiCloud/StoringPreferenceDatainiCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i-CH7

Comment: Thanks. Good explanation/motivation to go with one or the other!